# Styling the select element with appearance none css property

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the select element with appearance:none property. My html and  css is as in http://codepen.io/destinypallavi/pen/LRGoro

```css
select#lstReports {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #477928;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  /*position:relative;*/
}
select#lstReports + i {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: -26px;
  font-size: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<select id="lstReports">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
<i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-down"></i>
```

I am able to achieve the styling to somewhat. But in firefox, the default content of first `<option>` tag is showing?
How can I remove the default option tag value to stop appearing on the  styled select tag?

Comment: The appearance property isn't supported by many browsers, and then, not on all elements. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) says "Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For html 5 you can use hidden attribute to fix this.

```html
<select id="lstReports">
  <option hidden></option>
  <option>06</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjXLXO heres my codepen link